# error when trying to launch simulator on codenameone

Tags: eclipse, codenameone

I just installed codenameone on my eclipse IDE and I get this error whenever I launch the simulator. Version:Eclipse Oxygen Release (4.7.3) Build: 20180308-1800 .

```
WARNING: Could not open/create prefs root node Software\JavaSoft\Prefs at root 0x80000002. Windows RegCreateKeyEx(...) returned error code 5.
java.io.IOException: /theme.res not found
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.open(Resources.java:740)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:704)
at com.codename1.ui.util.Resources.openLayered(Resources.java:668)
at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:45)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:96)
at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:18)
at com.mycompany.myapp.HelloWorld.start(HelloWorld.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
java.lang.NullPointerException
at generated.StateMachineBase.initTheme(StateMachineBase.java:86)
at generated.StateMachineBase.startApp(StateMachineBase.java:49)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:31)
at generated.StateMachineBase.<init>(StateMachineBase.java:96)
at userclasses.StateMachine.<init>(StateMachine.java:18)
at com.mycompany.myapp.HelloWorld.start(HelloWorld.java:32)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.codename1.impl.javase.Executor$1$1.run(Executor.java:123)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.processSerialCalls(Display.java:1129)
at com.codename1.ui.Display.mainEDTLoop(Display.java:924)
at com.codename1.ui.RunnableWrapper.run(RunnableWrapper.java:120)
at com.codename1.impl.CodenameOneThread.run(CodenameOneThread.java:176)
```

Comment: How did you install codenameone?

Comment: I installed it from Eclipse Marketplace

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that you are running with JDK 8 (not 7, 9, 10 or 11). Make sure Eclipse itself is running on JDK 8 which is hard to see/configure as it's definable in the [eclipse.ini](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini) file. Make sure that the bin directory of JDK 8 is the first in the system path and that the environment variable `JAVA_HOME` points at JDK 8.

Assuming none of these panned out...

Check if the `theme.res` file is in the `src` directory. Press refresh (F5) and check the physical location on the hard disk.

Try creating a different project and see if a `theme.res` file is generated there. You can copy it to your project if it is.

Assuming that it isn't look at your home directory under the `.codenameone` folder. You should see a file called `designer.jar` or `designer_1.jar`. Is it there?

Does it launch when executed from the command line?

See this for more on tracking such issues https://www.codenameone.com/blog/tip-track-designer-guibuilder-issues.html